# Use the modal view displayed by UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: ios, document, docx

I've been thinking about the following possibility:

I am right now developing an app for displaying a different set of files(could be different formats), and use the content of these files to form 1 single file.

Because UIDocumentInteractionController could show content of formats that otherwise can't be viewed by my app(docx for example), wouldn't it be nice that I capture the modal view displayed by this controller and use it somewhere else?

I am wondering how can I access the content of presented UIDocumentInteractionController and capture it.

Any advice would be nice, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Screenshot** - Maybe I could do a screenshot of presentedViewController.view, but the resolution of captured image isn't ideal - limited to the screen resolution and not high enough to be viewed on a computer monitor.

Comment: Why is this posted as an answer? Why isn't this part of your question?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I think if I can find a way to increase the resolution of captured image, this could be the a proper answer.